# WooCommerce: add a few lists to wishlist by custom plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have custom plugin for first adding lists to Wishlist plugin (Woocommerce) by users.

I have custom step by step form, where user can choose number of lists (from 1 to 10) and enter titles and descriptions for these new lists.

There is Ajax request on the last step of my form.

How do I add these lists to database?

I'm trying to add by wp_insert_post( $my_post ) but I should add settings for postmeta table too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found:

```
WC_Wishlists_Wishlist::create_list($tittle));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could save the form results as [custom post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) with the results as [custom fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

Set the post type as not public and not set to not be in search results.

If they is no logic preformed on the wishlist you could set the data to array, and save it [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) in one field.

To send the data from front end (user page) to back end (server) you could or use [wp ajax admin](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) or through [wp-rest api](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/types/)

Save fields to custom post type example. Could be the field name is different in your site so set to according to your fields key

```
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['post_title'] ),
  'post_content'  => $_POST['post_content'],
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => array( 8,39 ),
  'post_type'     => 'event'
 );

// Insert the post into the database
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
// Updating the meta data (custom fields values)
if ( isset( $_POST['_wishlist_email'] ) ) {
  update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wishlist_email', sanitize_text_field(  $_POST['_wishlist_email'] ) );
}
```

More info about [saving custom fields in docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)

If this wishlist is from a ready plugin, you could look in the plugin code to see how the plugin handles the saving wishlist data.

Comment: yeah, I have funtction for using Ajax 
jQuery.post( ajaxurl, data, function( response ) { ... });
then ->
function set_post_information() { ... };
I can add new post with custom post type using wp_insert_post( );

But, also, I need to add some settings to `wp_postmeta` table:
http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/2016/08/16/0004/0023/299031/31/6392cfb044.jpg

Comment: I added a example how to save the fields after insert a custom post type by the $post_id returned

Comment: Thank you!
But the most problem for me - how to get data for `_wishlist_subscribers`, `_wishlist_items` and `_wishlist_sharing_key` fields